# On Jira (7.2.1), how can I view all issues that were, at some point, assigned to me?

Tags: jira

I searched and found:

```
assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser()
```

But this just returns a server error.

Anyone know a way I can achieve this?

Comment: I believe this correct. Try `assignee = currentUser()` and then `assignee was currentUser()` to see if they work in isolation. Another problem may be `currentUser()` - are you logged in?

Answer (score 1):

The JQL

```
assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser()
```

worked fine for me. Perhaps you had some other problem with JIRA?